# Select <p> tags separated with \n

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python to parse / clean an html document, but it is badly formed. For example

```
<p>\n<p>\n    Python initially inherited its parsing from C.  While this has been\ngenerally useful, there are some remnants which have been less useful\nfor Python, and should be eliminated.</p>\n</p>
```

I want to convert the `<p>\n<p>` to `<p>` but I can't seem to target the `\n` or any amount of whitespace between `<p>` tags.

**What I have tried so far**

```
html = "<p>\n<p>\n    Python initially inherited its parsing from C.  While this has been\ngenerally useful, there are some remnants which have been less useful\nfor Python, and should be eliminated.</p>\n</p>"
html = re.sub(re.compile("<p>\\n+<p>", "<p>", html))
```

However, this fails.

Comment: if all you want is a simple subsitution use .replace
i.e. `html = html.replace('<p>\n<p>', '<p>')`

Comment: @Nullman That doesn't work

Comment: it does for me under python 2. but you are still stuck with the closing tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
html = "<p>\n<p>\n    Python initially inherited its parsing from C.  While this has been\ngenerally useful, there are some remnants which have been less useful\nfor Python, and should be eliminated.</p>\n</p>"
html = re.sub(r'<p>[\n\s]+<p>[\n\s]*|<(\/)p>[\n\s]+<\/p>[\n\s]*', r"<\1p>", html)

print(html)
```

The output:

```
<p>Python initially inherited its parsing from C.  While this has been
generally useful, there are some remnants which have been less useful
for Python, and should be eliminated.</p>
```

The replacement `r"<\1p>"` implies closing tag sign `/` from the first capturing group `<(\/)p>` if it was matched

Answer (score 0):

assuming you also want to unscrew your closing tags, try the following regex
`re.sub('(\<\/?p\>)[\s\n]*(\<\/?p\>)', r'\1',html)`
note that this returns a copy of html, it doesnt change the original